# Show all nodes in the Getlocations map with diffrent marker colors per Content Type?

Tags: views

I have three content types with Getlocations Fields and try to get a map with views (type: Getlocations) showing all nodes as marker in the map with different marker colors with "Content Type Markers" activated in admin/config/services/getlocations. I get only blue markers, this is the "Default Content Map marker". What is the trick?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Look at [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1450132) - seems exactly what you want, but I have no getlocations myself here to test it, so I'm not posting an answer. If it will help you, I hope you'll post a nice answer based on it yourself. If it does not, at least you'll be able to add some data to your question.

Comment: I think [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/1450132) is the real one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in getlocations.views.inc line 96 & 97:

```
if (isset($options['node_marker__' . $location['type'] . '__' . $location['field_name']])) {
              $marker = $options['node_marker__' . $location['type'] . '__' . $location['field_name']];
```

You need to strtolower $location['type'], then it works:

```
if (isset($options['node_marker__' . strtolower($location['type']) . '__' . $location['field_name']])) {
              $marker = $options['node_marker__' . strtolower($location['type']) . '__' . $location['field_name']];
```

Comment: The maintainer will commit a fix today at [the project home](https://drupal.org/project/getlocations)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a views. Inside this views create 3 different **Overlay Layers** (views display name is 'OpenLayers Data Overlay'), one for each content type. You should do this on the same view by overriding each display (recommended).

2) Add a new Openalyers map (admin/structure/openlayers/maps/add). In the *Layers & Styles > Overlay Layers* section add the 3 layers with the marker types you prefer.

3) On the views described on 1 create a page display with format "Openlayers Map" and select the Map you have created on step 2.

Comment: Thank you tplcom but we want to use Getlocations only.